# Draw lines using Device Context over a CImage object

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, drawing, gdi

Im building a MFC c++ application in which i let the user read an image, draw lines on it and then save it.

so i have a "CImage" object which is called "Image" in which the user loads the image to.

and i have a device context object and i was able to draw lines on it
*the device context object that is* in run-time using "OnLButtonDown" and "OnLButtonUp" event handlers.

i then let the user save the image using "CImage.save" .. the image is saved but the device context drawn lines aren't there which is to be expected ..
but I DO want them to appear in the saved image..

the question is how can i get the device context Object to affect my CImage Object?

this is the event handler for mouse button down

```
void CProFilterDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    curser =point;
    if (draw && Boundry.PtInRect(point) )
    {
        CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    }

}
```

and this one when the mouse button is up

```
void CProFilterDlg::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (draw && Boundry.PtInRect(curser) && Boundry.PtInRect(point))
    {
        CClientDC dc(this);
        dc.MoveTo(curser);
        dc.LineTo(point);
        CDialogEx::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
    }


}
```

this is where i load my Cimage object

```
void CProFilterDlg::OnBnClickedBtnBrowse()
{
    CFileDialog Browse(true);
    if(Browse.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
         ImagePath = Browse.GetPathName();
    }

        image.Load(ImagePath);
}
```

and this is where i save my CImage

```
void CProFilterDlg::OnBnClickedSave()
{
    CFileDialog Save(true);
    if(Save.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        ImagePath = Save.GetPathName();
    }
    image.Save(ImagePath,Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
}
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the DC?  You haven't shown any pertinent code.

Comment: i have edited the post to show my DC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've shown, it appears you are using the wrong DC.  You seem to be using the DC for the dialog (ie. CCLientDC) and **not** the actual CImage.  You should be constructing the DC from

[CImage::GetDC ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23hdhzz.aspx).

That DC will have the currently selected bitmap.

Comment: the GetDC() only gives me an HDC handle to device context 
i need to use functions like moveto() and lineto() and its availabe only with the CDC how can i use those fuctions with the GetDC()?

Comment: You can construct a DC from the HDC.  Look at the methods of CDC.  You'll find _FromHandle_ allows you to create a CDC.

Comment: i wrote:
    HDC Hdc =image.GetDC();
        CDC dc;
      pdc=dc.FromHandle(Hdc);
      dc.MoveTo(curser);
      dc.LineTo(point);
but asserion ERROR occured and when debugging i noticed the Hdc is unused " Unable to read Memory" 
 :D 
well that's strange :D

Comment: You didn't read the documentation closely.  _FromHandle_ returns a pointer to a CDC, *not* an actual CDC.  You need to change the way you call the methods by using the pointer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [CImage:BitBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c431046z.aspx)? It is used to copy a bitmap from the source device context to current device context.

Comment: well that would help me draw on a copy of the image.. i still need to put the device context with the copied bitmap into a CImage object so i can use the CImage.save